# C pointers and memory

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning C and now I hit a wall. Its difficult for me to understand pointers.

Imagine I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define DELTA 33

int calls, seed=356;

int sum_ds(int a){    
 int d=DELTA;          
 calls++;               
 return a+d+seed; 
}                       

int main() {
    int num;                                
    int *ptr;
    int **handle;

     num = 14;                              
     ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));  
     handle = &ptr;
     *(*handle+0) = num;                    
     *(*handle+1) = num+1;  
     *ptr = num-2;      
     ptr = &num;        
     *ptr = sum_ds(num-2);
}
```

Lets go step by step trough my understanding.

1 - int calls creates a variable named calls and doesn't initializes it so it contains rubbish. It is stored on DATA and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAA.

2 - int seeds creates a variable named seeds initialized with the integer 356. It is stored on DATA and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAB.

3 - int num creates a variable named num and doesn't initializes it so it contains rubbish. It is stored on the STACK and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAC.

4 - int *ptr creates a pointer to int and does not assign any address to it. It is stored on the STACK and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAD.

5 - int **handle creates a pointer to a pointer of int and does not assign any address to it. It is stored on the STACK and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAE. (MANY DOUBTS HERE)

6 - num = 14 goes to the address 0xFFAC and stores the number 14 on it. It's done in the STACK.

7 - ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int)) On the HEAP it's assigned memory size for 2 ints and the address of the first memory byte (let's say 0xFFZZ) is stored (on STACK) on ptr so now *ptr points to that memory address.

8 - handle = &ptr handle now points to ptr. I believe it now points to whatever is on 0xFFZZ (MANY DOUBTS HERE)

9 - *(*handle+0) = num the pointer to the pointer of int now its assigned with the value of num (14) (MANY MANY MANY MANY DOUBTS HERE)

10 - *(*handle+1) = num+1 the pointer of pointer plus one of int now its assigned with the value of num + 1 (15) (MANY MANY MANY MANY DOUBTS HERE)

11 - *ptr = num-2 the value point by ptr it's assigned with the value of num - 2 (12). I believe it goes to the memory address 0xFFZZ and stores there the number 12.

12 - ptr = &num ptr now points to num, i believe it now points to 0xFFAC.

13 - *ptr = sum_ds(num-2) the value pointed by ptr is the returned value of sum_ds. I belive 0xFFAC it's assigned with 401 (12+33+356)

Is this right?

Comment: the size of int is not 1 byte ... it's 4 bytes (or 8 bytes). So in step 2, the address can't be 0xFFAB (because that's address is the second byte of the int in step 1)

Comment: @Aziz: An `int` will *typically* be larger than one byte, but it's not strictly required (though if it was only one byte, you'd have to have at least 16 bits in a byte).

Comment: +1 to counter the unjustified downvote.

Comment: @PéterTörök Thanks for the up vote. Didn't understand why somebody gave me an downvote :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1 - int calls creates a variable named calls and doesn't initializes it so it contains rubbish. It is stored on DATA and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAA.
>
> 2 - int seeds creates a variable named seeds initialized with the integer 356. It is stored on DATA and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAB.

One little detail: `sizeof(int)` is greater than 1 (it is 4 on most mainstream platforms, so the 2nd address could not be 1 higher than the 1st. Other than that, AFAIK you are correct so far.

> 3 - int num creates a variable named num and doesn't initializes it so it contains rubbish. It is stored on the STACK and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAC.
>
> 4 - int *ptr creates a pointer to int and does not assign any address to it. It is stored on the STACK and let's say with the memory address 0xFFAD.

Another little detail: on most mainstream platforms, the stack grows downward, so the 4th address would be less than the 3rd. Other than that, AFAIK you are correct so far. (Moreover, addresses on the data segment, the heap and the stack would be rather different in real life.)

> 7 - ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int)) On the HEAP it's assigned memory size for 2 ints and the address of the first memory byte (let's say 0xFFZZ) is stored (on STACK) on ptr so now *ptr points to that memory address.

To be nitpicky, 'Z' is not a hexadecimal number :-) So let's say it is `0x1000` instead.

> 8 - handle = &ptr handle now points to ptr. I believe it now points to whatever is on 0xFFZZ (MANY DOUBTS HERE)

No, `handle` now contains the address of `ptr`, that is `0xFFAD`. *Indirectly* though - through `ptr` - it indeed points to `0x1000` (was `0xFFZZ` in your example).

> 9 - *(*handle+0) = num the pointer to the pointer of int now its assigned with the value of num (14) (MANY MANY MANY MANY DOUBTS HERE)

Basically correct. The notation you use is not the easiest to deal with, which makes it more difficult for you to follow what's going on. After step 8, `*handle` is equivalent to `ptr`. And due to pointers and arrays being interchangeable in many common situations, *(ptr+0) is equivalent to `ptr[0]`, and also to `*ptr`.

> 10 - *(*handle+1) = num+1 the pointer of pointer plus one of int now its assigned with the value of num + 1 (15) (MANY MANY MANY MANY DOUBTS HERE)

Similar to the previous point, you are in effect assigning `ptr[1] = num+1`. Keep in mind though that `ptr` is `int*`, so the address difference between `ptr` and `ptr + 1` equals to `sizeof(int)`, which is, as mentioned above, usually 4.

> 11 - *ptr = num-2 the value point by ptr it's assigned with the value of num - 2 (12). I believe it goes to the memory address 0xFFZZ and stores there the number 12.

Yes, this overwrites the value set in step 9.

> 12 - ptr = &num ptr now points to num, i believe it now points to 0xFFAC.

Correct.

> 13 - *ptr = sum_ds(num-2) the value pointed by ptr is the returned value of sum_ds. I belive 0xFFAC it's assigned with 401 (12+33+356)

Correct. Since the previous step made `*ptr` equivalent to `num`, this call is also equivalent to `num = sum_ds(num-2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. My memory "notation" was for "illustration" purpose only. I know that it's not as I mention but didn't knew that the stack grows downward so thanks for pointing that out. Following your explanations now I'm stuck on point 8 because I don't know if what I've wrote on points 5 and 6 are right. Basically I don't know what handle is...

Comment: @Favolas, sorry, I left out points 5 & 6 because they are correct, `handle` is indeed a pointer to pointer to `int`.

Comment: @Favolas, btw you can print out addresses and pointers to check their real value at any point, e.g. `printf("handle is at address 0x%08X, pointing to 0x%08X, and *handle is 0x%08X .\n", &handle, handle, *handle);` .

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Made this code http://pastebin.com/DNA6h60t (sorry but don't know how to insert code on comments) to see memory address's so I can understand better. Please note that the printf that are commented give seg fault if uncommented. Basically my problem is handle. I know that it's created a pointer to a pointer of ints with int **handle but what are handle and *handle? Are they even "created"?

Comment: @Favolas, dereferencing an uninitalized pointer is indeed undefined behaviour, i.e. don't ever do it in production code, even for debugging purposes. So you should be able to print out `&handle` and `handle` anytime, but you must not try to print out `*handle` or `**handle` before it is properly initialized (in your case, the statement `handle = &ptr` does that).

Answer (score 1):

Since `calls` is outside any function, it's a `static` variable. Static variables are initialized to 0.

Since `num` is a local variable (`auto` storage class) it is *not* initialized.

At your point 9, `*(*handle+0) = num;` is probably easiest to decipher by keeping in mind that `handle = &ptr`, therefore `*handle = ptr`, so this is basically equivalent to `*(ptr+0) = num;`, which is (in turn) equivalent to `ptr[0] = num;`.

For point 10, you get pretty much the same thing, except a `+1` in both cases, so it's saying `ptr[1] = num+1;`.

For point 11, `*ptr=num-2;` overwrites what was written in point 9 -- i.e., *ptr is the same as `*(ptr+0)`, so this is equivalent to `ptr[0] = num-2;`

You're correct in point 12 that `ptr` has been set to point at `num`. That means in point 13, the assignment is equivalent to `num=sum_ds(num-2);`

Answer (score 1):

A variable has an address and stores at that address are the value that you just put:

```
int a = 10;
```

Right?

A pointer is a kind of variable that stores the address of another variable.
So...

```
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;
```

This means that "p" stores the address of "a" that has the value that you want to use.

Execute this code below and you'll understand:
    printf("%p %p %d %d\n", p, &a, *p, a);